# Drupal taxonomy subscription sends out duplicate emails (Pressflow 6.31, Subscriptions or Messaging and Notifications)

Tags: email, drupal, messaging, subscriptions

I have a website sending out email alerts when a story is posted. Customers subscribe to taxonomy terms to receive only the stories they are interested in. I'm fighting with a weird issue - some of our subscribers complain that they get duplicate emails, I've checked smtp logs and they are right. The problem has first happened with the Messaging and Notifications (after 4 years of stable work), at first only a few users were getting duplicates for some emails and in the end every user was getting every email twice. I assumed it was connected with those modules and replaced them with Subscriptions. Now the problem occurs again. I have two questions:

1) Has anyone got an idea where I should look? I'm really lost. I'm using Mandrill (mandrillapp.com) as SMTP server and used PHPMailer for connection in Drupal (just replaced it with SMTP, hope it helps, will know tomorrow). The website has been hosted with Omega8.cc since the beginning of the year, and the problem occured after this update: https://omega8.cc/boa-221-full-edition-305 but the tech support say it's not connected with my issue and they can't help.

2) I've looked at the subscriptions_queue table and see the sqid column, which is the only one that seems to be related to nodes - how do I find which sqid links to which node? I hope to run a filter on the table to remove duplicate entries if they are there.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm really lost
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can a story have multiple taxonomy terms? I haven't used Subscriptions in Production yet, so I'm not sure of the logic it uses when pulling the list to send. If a story has taxonomy Birds and Bees, and a user is subscribed to both Birds and Bees, it is default practice to send out 1 message for each taxonomy match? It seems like there should be a filter/configuration somewhere to prevent this.

Comment: Yes, a story can have multiple taxonomy terms. With Subscriptions it's like this: I have several vocabularies with parent and child terms, if a user subscribes, say, to a parent term and to a child term (which he shouldn't really do, but they do it all the time), i.e. Bees and Awesome bees, and I post a story tagged with both terms, Subscriptions will still send out only one email. However, if a story has tags from 2 different vocabularies, i.e. Bees and Forest, then 2 emails will be sent out.

Comment: Then the behavior you're seeing is by design. You'll probably need to do some custom coding to make sure Subscriptions doesn't send out multiple messages for the same Story. Alternatively, you may be able to use Rules instead of Subscritions.

Comment: No, the problem is not with Subscriptions, as it used to work just fine, and still duplicate emails are only observed randomly. Further investigation revealed the problem is with duplicate cron runs, which should not be happening at all. Tech support suggests it may be a Drupal core issue, I created a request here: https://drupal.org/node/2259905